# Setting error reporting based on config

Tags: php, error-handling

```
    public function setErrorReporting() {
    if($this->debugMode == 0) {
        error_reporting(0);
    } elseif($this->debugMode == 1) {
        error_reporting("E_ALL");
    } elseif($this->debugMode == 2) {
        error_reporting("E_ALL");
        // Also log errors
    }
```

I want to change the error reporting based on a value from a config file. (eithor 0, 1 or 2)
But if I ever wanted to increase the options then it won't scale like this.

Is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: Instead of setting the error_reporting based in your code, why not switch php.ini files, based on environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the function take an optional argument. 
This argument `$mode` could be your user defined logging level that would skip the normal logic to determine the reporting level.

An example could be:

```
public function set_error_reporting($mode = null) {

    $reporting = null;

    if(!is_null($mode)) {

        $reporting = $mode;

    }else{

        switch($this->debug_mode) {

            case 0:
                $reporting = 0;
                break;

            case 1:
                $reporting = E_ALL;
                break;

            case 2:
                $reporting = E_ALL;
                ini_set('log_errors', 1);  // Enable error logging
                break;

            default:
                $reporting = null;
                break;

        }
    }

    // Check if no reporting level was selected

    if(is_null($reporting)) {
        // throw exception (preferred) or emit an error.
    }

    error_reporting($reporting);
}
```

Then to set the error reporting level automatically.

```
$obj->set_error_reporting();
```

Or if you would like to specify another reporting level from a config file.

```
$level = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;  // Log all errors except notices.

$obj->set_error_reporting($level);
```

This will require you to fetch the reporting level configuration from outside the function. You could also add more `case` statements to the `switch` if you know they will be used beforehand.

Let me know if you have any questions or there is something you would like to point out.

Best regards.